# FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = '

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to upload a thumbnail created by this [library](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) of a video.In app i am sending images through same method but when i try to send this thumbnail  it throw exception FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path

this is how  i am creating thumnail

```
final uint8list = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
        video: _videoFile!.path,
        imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
      );

      /// uploading both thumbnail and video
      _videos.add(
        VideosModel(
          id: await FileUploader.uploadFile(_videoFile, "POST_VIDEO"),
          posterId:
              await FileUploader.uploadFile(File.fromRawPath(uint8list!), "POST_IMG"),
        ),
      );
    }
```

this is how i am sending images

```
static Future<String> uploadFile(File file, String ref) async {
    String fileName = file.path.split('/').last;
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(file.path, filename: fileName), // error is here in file.path
    });
    Response response =
        await UATHTTPClient().dio.post("v1/aws/upload", data: formData, queryParameters: {
      "ref": ref,
    });
    return response.data['id'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, I've never used the video_thumbnail package, so I might be wrong, you are the expert here, but from reading the docs, it seems like the method `VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData` only stores the thumbnail as an array of bytes in memory, so it's not actually a file, in order to create a file, you need the `VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile` method, and pass onto it a thumbnailPath parameter so it knows where to save it.
As I said, I literally know nothing about video_thumbnail, so if I'm wrong I apologize!